# How can I make a database on RDP? (phpmyadmin)

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have RDP I have a lot of hosted sites on it using `IIS`.

I'm willing to make a forum which requires a DB, in my case `http://localhost/` working but `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` is not working.

I tried to re-install `wwwroot/phpmyadmin` but it still shows `error 500`.

I also tried with xampp too, with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem and i have another problem now.
i fixed that error by install Mysql Windows 5.5

after setting The username to root & pass to root  in the installationg
i can't login to /phpmyadmin using the same username & pass

Comment: Please focus your answer on just the answer. New questions should be posted as new questions. You can cross-reference these questions via links to provide background and follow-up.